# Example of a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

For a normal variety $X$ denote by $\operatorname{Div}(X)$ the space of *Weil divisors* and $\operatorname{CDiv}(X)$ the *Cartier divisors*. An element of $\operatorname{CDiv}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is called a $\mathbb{Q}$*-Cartier divisor*. The example below is intended to show that in general $\operatorname{CDiv}(X) \subset \operatorname{CDiv}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is a proper inclusion.

*Example:* Let $X$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^3_k$
defined by $xy + z^2 = 0$. That is $X=\operatorname{Spec} \ k[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$.One can show that $X$ is normal (that's because the only singular point of $X$ is the origin. Now we can use Serre's criterion).

Take the closed subset $D = V(y, z)$ in $X$, then it is a prime divisor isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_k$. Two claims I not understand:

I) Why is $O_X(D)$ not invertible or equivalently $D$ *not* a Cartier divisor?

II) Why is, on the other hand, $O_X(2D)$ a
free $O_X$-Module (=invertible)?

What we know is that $D$ is a prime divisor on $X$ (a irreducible codimension one subvariety). That is for open $U \subset X$

$$\mathcal{O}_X(nD)(U):=\{ f\in K(X)\;|\; (f)\geq - nD|_U \}$$

For I) it is sufficient to show that $\mathcal{O}_X(D)(X)$ isn't generated by a single element as $k[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$-module. I not know how can I do it.

For II) I know that $y^{-1}, z^{-2}  \in \mathcal{O}_X(2D)(X)$ and $z^{-2}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$. My guess was that $y^{-1}$ is a promissing candidate to be the single generator of $\mathcal{O}_X(2D)$ as $O_X$ module, But $x^{-1} \not \in k[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$ , hence my confusion if $y^{-1}$ is the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience I alter your notation a bit: $k[x,y,z]=k[X,Y,Z]/(XY+Z^2)$.

As for (I) it suffices to show that the ideal $(y,z)\mathcal{O}_{X,(0,0,0)}$ is not principal. (Note that an ideal can be invertible without being generated by one element globally, so your corresponding remark is wrong.)

Suppose $(y,z)\mathcal{O}_{X,(0,0,0)}$ is a principal ideal, then one of the two elements $y$ or $z$ generates the ideal. Hence either $y=\frac{a(x,y,z)}{b(x,y,z)}z$ or $z=\frac{a(x,y,z)}{b(x,y,z)}y$, where $b\in k[X,Y,Z]$ is a polynomial with a non-zero constant coefficient. In the first case one arrives at the equation

$b(X,Y,Z)Y=a(X,Y,Z)Z+f(X,Y,Z)(XY+Z^2).$

The polynomial on the right-hand-side has no monomial of the form $cY$, $c\in k^\ast$, while the polynomial on the left-hand-side does. A similar argument holds in the second case.

Comment: For (I) you use a more *general fact* that if $A$ is a ring, $I \subset A$ an ideal und $p \subset A$ is a prime ideal, then if $I \cdot A_p$ isn't principal as $A_p$-module ($A_p$ is the localization of $A$ at $p$), then $I$ isn't also principal $A$-module,right?

Comment: You suggest to use a similar argument for (II). Do you mean it in the sense that the *general fact* can be reversed?  ie if for all primes $p$ the $A_p$-module $I \subset A$ is principal then $I$ is also principal as $A$ module? Or do you mean it in a simpler way? Since I'm not sure why to show that $O_X(2D)$ is principal it suffice to show that the stalk $(O_X(2D))_p$ is principal ideal of $k[x,y,z]_p$ for $p=(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Your first comment seems again to signal, that you think invertible (fractional) ideals must be principal. But this is not true and it is not what I am using. I am using the following equivalence: a fractional ideal $I$ of a domain $A$ is invertible if and only if it is finitely generated and for every maximal (or prime) ideal $p$ the $A_p$-module $IA_p$ is principal. As for your second comment: in my post I say nothing about (II) since I'm not sure about how you define $\mathcal{O}_X(2D)$. Using discrete valuations like in Hartshorne, or reflexive ideal sheaves?

Comment: I see possibly my problem. Is your definition of invertible ideal that the $A_p$-module $I A_p$ is principal at every prime $p$ equivalent to: for every point or prime $p$ there *exist* an open affine subscheme $U(x) \subset X$ with $O_X(2D)(U(p))$ is free or rank $1$ as $O_X(U(x))$-module?

So if I understand you correctly then my error in (II) asking if $y^{-1}$ is a local generator was that in general we cannot expect that $O_X(2D)(X)$ is principal fractional ideal of $k[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)=O_X(X)$ but it *becomes* at

Comment: every $p \in X$ after shrinking $X$ to a smaller affine neighborhood $U(p) \subset X$ of $p$ a principal fractional ideal $O_X(nD)(D(p))$ of $O_X(D(p))$? For example, the problem I explained above with $x^{-1} \not \in k[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$ can be avoided if we localize $k[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$ in $x$ and so on. Was this your point?

Comment: The definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(nD)$ I'm working with is the one with discrete valuations like in Hartshorne. So you check if $(f)\geq - nD|_U$ holds in every dimension $1$ stalk $O_{X,d}$ which is a DVR where $\overline{\{d\}}=D'$ is a component of $D$. That means to check if the maximal $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $f \in m_d^l$ is bigger than $-n$.

Comment: The first two of the three last comments you posted are correct. I'll try to come back to (II) - no time at the moment.

Comment: a marginal note: I'm bit curious about the other definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(nD)$ using reflexive ideal sheaves you mentioned in your comment. I haven't seen anywhere this approach. Could you sketch it briefly when you will have more time?